# Trying to use ack and getingg ban from discord Why?

Tags: discord, discord.py

Code:

```
import discord

token = 'mytoken'

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Online!")
    for guild in client.guilds:
        print(guild)
        await guild.ack()


client.run(token, bot=False)
```

I am Getting ban from discord every time i using this

The owner of this website (discordapp.com) has banned you temporarily from accessing this website.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't discord support

Comment: @jonrsharpe I saw ack() in the docs I think it’s ok to use it or I am wrong?

Comment: Self-bots on [user accounts](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#bot-vs-user-accounts) [are forbidden now](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you sends more than normal human requests-per-second.
You can try to fix it with `await asyncio.sleep()` but I suggest you just stop using selfbots.

Possible fix:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Online!")
    for guild in client.guilds:
        print(guild)
        await guild.ack()
        await asyncio.sleep(10) # Sleep for 10 seconds
```

Comment: I don’t know if I stop with discord selfbot I am not making a program for bad like raid a server I am making it for me but btw thanks for the answer I will check it soon